# Why Intent twice the same activity in OnTouch method?

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

When I touch the screen, the OnTouch method is called twice. 
So the Intent of the new activity in the method "showdetails"  load the activity with the view associated twice also. 
Why? I just need one...

```
public class DeptFragment extends Fragment implements OnTouchListener {

Context mContext = getActivity();
ImageView cacheImage,targetImage; 
ListView List;
ArrayList<String> tabDepartement;
ArrayList<String> tabCommunes;
int codeDepartementCrt;
Departement DepartementCrt;
List<Commune> listCommuneCrt;
Bundle nomBundle;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState) ;
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dept_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedState);
    mContext=getActivity();
    View mView = getView();

    targetImage = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.targetDeptImage);

    targetImage.setOnTouchListener(this); 



}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    View mView = getView();

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.cacheDeptImage);

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());

    int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
    int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
    int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);

    showDetails(redValue,greenValue,blueValue);

    return true;
```

}

```
/**
 * Helper function to show the details of a selected item, by starting a
 * whole new activity in which it is displayed.
 */
void showDetails(int red, int green, int blue) {

    DepartementCrt=rechercherDepartement(red,green,blue);

    if (DepartementCrt != null) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getActivity(), DeptDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("code", DepartementCrt.Code);
                startActivity(intent);
    }
}


private Departement rechercherDepartement(int redValue, int greenValue, int blueValue) {
    DepartementRepository departementRepository=new DepartementRepository(mContext);
    Departement departement;

    departementRepository.Open();
    departement= departementRepository.rechercherDepartement(redValue, greenValue, blueValue);
    departementRepository.Close();

    return departement;
}
```

}

Comment: why don't you simply use onClickListener for your Image?

Comment: @Andro Selva : because I need the "motionevent" to take color of the pixel.

Answer (score 4):

The on touch method is called for different event type.

Some of these are:

- MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
- MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
- MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE

Maybe you should consider to evaluate the event using a switch like this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

        int action = me.getAction();

        switch( action ) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            break;
        default:

        }
 }
```

And finally, if you want evaluate just the click action on a view you should use the View.onClickListener interface.

```
myView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are touching image in quick Succession.You should set a flag and toggle it once you detect touch first time.

Change your code to following.

```
Boolean consumeTouch = true;

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (consumeTouch) {

            consumeTouch = false;

            View mView = getView();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mView
                    .findViewById(R.id.cacheDeptImage);

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable())
                    .getBitmap();
            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

            int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
            int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
            int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);

            showDetails(redValue, greenValue, blueValue);

            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```